# angularjs accordion is-disabled

Tags: angularjs, accordion, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to recreate this:

```
...
<accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
  This content is straight in the template.
</accordion-group>
...
```

Like in the angular-ui-bootstrap official example but since I need html markup on my accordion-heading I'm using it in the following way but it seems that this way, the "is-disabled" doesn't work:

```
<accordion-group>
    <accordion-heading is-disabled="true">
        <i class="fa fa-glass"></i>Dérivés
    </accordion-heading>
</accordion-group>
```

Note that I want a variable in place of the boolean but even the boolean doesn't work.  I also tested the directive on the  tag with no success.

It would be nice to have some lights on this problem, thanks.

Comment: Try placing the is-disabled attribute in <accordion-group>.  The accordion will be disabled, but it won't give a muted text (gray appearance).  Not sure how to do that part.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/yekOkUoEdWMCyRGO15PB?p=preview

Comment: @eer by overriding `.text-muted` css class with custom rules for muted text.

Comment: Thanks.  Turns out I had 0.10 installed.  By installing 0.11.2 everything works as expected within accordion-group tag.